# How do I get the "right" LibreOffice Calc icon into the launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons, libreoffice, unity-dash

I just uninstalled the pre-installed LibreOffice from Ubuntu 16.04 and installed the 5.0.5-version. Now there occured a problem with the launcher icon that (I think) wasn't there before:

The icon shown for Calc has a very bad quality and always says that it is an untitled document, even when the opened document is clearly titled

[image]

This problem does not occur for the other LibreOffice programs, as you can see at the Writer-icon above the Calc-icon.

When I search for LibreOffice in the Dash, two different possibilities show up for Calc

[image]

"untitled 1 - LibreOffice Calc" and 
"LibreOffice 5.0 Calc"

The latter is the right one. But even when I click on it, it opens the first icon/application, although at first it shows the right (high-quality) icon in the launcher for a second. Both open the 5.0.5-version, but with the wrong icon and the wrong title. 
The same problem occurs with `LibreOffice Main`.

I have read a bit about icons in Unity at some websites (also this one), which lead me to the folder `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`, where I also found the "ugly" images, which are related to .`xdesktop` -files. Interestingly, in this folder, only the `.xdesktop` -file of `Calc` and `Main` have an icon at all, not the others.

Has it got something to do with the files in the folder `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/`? What about the files in the folder `/usr/share/icons`? Is it related to the icon-theme, which I changed?
Does anyone know how I can get the right icon and the right `Calc` -application to be used? Is there possibly a remainder of the previous `LibreOffice` version on the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Default directories for  launchers

The two default directories for `.desktop` files (launchers) are:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

for gloablly installed applications, and

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

for locally installed applications (`~` stands for your home directory, `/home/yourname`) , or local versions of the launchers.

#### About LibreOffice

LibreOffice however is a bit of a stranger in our midst, if it comes to `.desktop` files.

While the ***default*** (Ubuntu) version of LibreOffice stores its `.desktop` files, as usual, in

```
/usr/share/applications
```

the ***downloaded*** version stores them in

```
/usr/local/share/applications
```

That is, *links* to the launchers. The real launchers are in

```
/opt/libreoffice5.0/share/xdg/
```

#### What happened

There are two options:

1. Somehow, you have a local copy of the `Libreoffice` launcher in `~/.local/share/applications`. If so, it will overrule all other occurrences of the same launcher (as mentioned, `~` stands for your home directory, `/home/yourname`). If so, remove the file(s), log out and back in.
2. the launcher in `/usr/share/applications` was left behind for some reason, by an error during uninstall. If the first option is not the case:

   - Navigate to `/usr/share/applications` open a terminal window, type:

     ```
     sudo rm
     ```

     and subsequently drag the `LibreOffice Calc` launcher over into the terminal window in order to insert the file-directory. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Of course, you can also do that by typing the command:

     ```
     sudo rm /usr/local/share/libreoffice-calc.desktop
     ```

     and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   - Log out and back in and it should be fixed.

Comment: I am on version 6.3 of LibreOffice and looks like these filelocation do not apply anymore...

Answer (score 0):

There was also the question about the images (icons) for LibreOffice. Well, even if that was directly asked: Personally I was searching for the folder containing that file countless times, and I always found this stackoverflow entry, which was not helpful in this regard. It mentioned the folder `/usr/share/app-install/desktop`, but that did not contain any files for me (Ubuntu 21.04).

Thus, in case anybody needs this as well: The libreoffice icons are stored in:

```
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same icon problem when I upgraded from LibreOffice to LibreOffice 7.2, the icons weren't applied to LibreOffice like every other app.  The solution was to go into the .desktop entry and remove the 7.2 wording

Run each one of these at a time and change the entry to the below -

```
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-base.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-calc.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-draw.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-impress.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-math.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-startcenter.desktop
sudo vim libreoffice7.2-writer.desktop
```

Here is one example for writer:-

```
  #Icon=libreoffice7.2-writer
  Icon=libreoffice-writer
```