# Ubuntu 16.04 - Libre Office Icons Appearnce Change

Tags: icons, libreoffice, 16.04

I have successfully upgraded Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 but now I find the icons in the Libre Office suite have changed to a very simple, almost washed out, appearance. It is now difficult to know what some icons stand for.

How can I restore the icons to their former appearance, or something better than what I now have?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. Does it solve your problem?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/763335/how-do-i-get-the-right-libreoffice-calc-icon-into-the-launcher

Comment: Tools > Options > View > Icon size and style?

Comment: @DKBose: Thank you, that worked. With the upgrade to 16.04 the default style was reset to **Breeze**. Changing it to **Human** returned the icon style to what I had prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

Click on Tools --> Options --> Libre Office --> View -- Icon & Style --> Human / Galaxy

Try and see if this work out for you.